# Don't see the connection in proof inverse modulo

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Let $x$ and $y$ be integers such that $rx \equiv ry \pmod{60}$. Thus, $$ rx - ry = r(x - y) = 60t $$for some integer $t$. This means that $60 \mid r(x - y)$. But, since $\gcd(r, 60) = 1$, we know that $60 \mid (x - y)$. Thus, $x \equiv y \pmod{60}$. This means that when $x \not\equiv y \pmod{60}$, we have $rx \not\equiv ry \pmod{60}$.

It is with the last sentence that I have trouble in understanding.

I see a proof that if $rx \equiv ry \pmod{60}$ for integers $x$ and $y$, then $x$ and $y$ are members of the same modulo-60 residue class. If they are not members of the same modulo-60 residue class, i.e. $x \not\equiv y \pmod{60}$, then how can one make the conclusion that $rx \not\equiv ry \pmod{60}$? Is it so trivial that I'm overthinking this? How does this conclusion flow from the conclusion of the first part?

Comment: They show that $rx\equiv ry \Rightarrow x\equiv y$. The last statement is simply the contrapositive of this statemtent. Remember that $(P\Rightarrow Q)\Leftrightarrow (\neg Q\Rightarrow \neg P)$.

Comment: @Mathematician42 That is very clever! From elementary number theory to logic :-)